# Filling objects with flood fill in java

Tags: java, flood-fill

here is my problem. I created a four-leaf clover and I want to fill him with colour.
I have this simple seed_fill (flood_fill):

```
package projekt;

class SeedFill {        
private int width;
private int height;
private int[] canvas;

public SeedFill(int width, int height, int[] canvas){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.canvas = canvas;
}
public void seed_fill(int x, int y){
    int coord = 3*x + 3*y * width;

    if( x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height)return;

    if(canvas[coord] == 0 && canvas[coord+1] == 255 && canvas[coord+2] == 0)return;

    if(canvas[coord] == 255 && canvas[coord+1] == 255 && canvas[coord+2] == 255)return;

    //colors
    canvas[coord] = 255;
    canvas[coord+1] = 255;
    canvas[coord+2] = 255; 

    //recursive
    seed_fill(x,y-1);
    seed_fill(x,y+1);
    seed_fill(x-1,y);
    seed_fill(x+1,y);
}   
}
```

The clover is your 400x400 pixels big in total

When I run the project it show me this error message:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError 
at lines of code 14, 30 and 31

apparently there is a problem with the recursive, but I'm not that smart to figure it out how to change code to fill that big object.

Thanks for any advices and help.

Comment: It looks like each call to `seed_fill` calls `seed_fill` for each of its neighbours. So if you call it on `(a,b)`, and that calls it on `(c,d)`, then _that_ will again call it on `(a,b)`. You get infinite recursion. You need to rearrange your function calls and checks to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

`seed_fill()` calls `seed_fill()` for its 4 neighbors, which calls `seed_fill()` for its 4 neighbors, which calls `seed_fill()` for its 4 neighbors, which calls `seed_fill()` for its 4 neighbors, etc.

So you end up with an endless reursive call. For example calling it for (0, 1) calls it for (1, 1), which calls it for (0, 1), which calls it for (1, 1), etc.